# Access and add nodes at specific position in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a multi level JS object. I need to insert other nodes(arrays or objects) in a specific node at a specified position.

Tried the following methods

```
obj[0] = {'key':'value'};
obj["position"] = {'key':'value'};
```

nothing worked for me.

This is my object:

```
var obj = {

      'id' : '1',
      'text' : 'post',
      'fill' : 'transparent',
      'img': 'assets/images/post-ico.png',
      'image' : 'test',
      'type' : 'component',
      'url' : 'test.com',
      'key': 'F',
      'fields' : 
            [{'name' : 'remote_address',
                'value' : '127.0.0.1',
                'group': 'F',
                'text' : 'Request',
                'fields' : 
                      [{'name' : 'remote_address',
                          'value' : '127.0.0.1',
                          'text' : 'Body',},              
                        {'name' : 'remote_address',
                          'value' : '127.0.0.1',
                          'text' : 'Headers'
                        }
                      ]
              },            
              {'name' : 'remote_address',
              'group': 'F',
              'value' : '127.0.0.1',
              'text' : 'Response',
              'fields' : 
              [{'name' : 'remote_address',
                'value' : '127.0.0.1',
                'text' : 'Headers',
                },
                {'name' : 'remote_address',
                  'value' : '127.0.0.1',
                  'text' : 'Body',
                  'fields':[]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
        };
```

This is what I want to add to the object data in the `fields:[]` property

```
{'name' : 'remote_address',
 'value' : '127.0.0.1',
 'text' : 'Headers',
}
```

I was able to add the data as a node to the objbut it was not in the position where I wanted it to be.

Help me insert the date at the specified position.

I want the data as the value of the last `fields:[]` property, and I want it within those square brackets

Comment: `obj.fields.push({'name' : 'remote_address','value' : '127.0.0.1','text' : 'Headers',})`? it's not _really_ json, it's just a normal object with an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to navigate the object

```js
var obj = { 'id': '1', 'text': 'post', 'fill': 'transparent', 'img': 'assets/images/post-ico.png', 'image': 'test', 'type': 'component', 'url': 'test.com', 'key': 'F', 'fields': [{ 'name': 'remote_address', 'value': '127.0.0.1', 'group': 'F', 'text': 'Request', 'fields': [{ 'name': 'remote_address', 'value': '127.0.0.1', 'text': 'Body', }, { 'name': 'remote_address', 'value': '127.0.0.1', 'text': 'Headers' } ] }, { 'name': 'remote_address', 'group': 'F', 'value': '127.0.0.1', 'text': 'Response', 'fields': [{ 'name': 'remote_address', 'value': '127.0.0.1', 'text': 'Headers', }, { 'name': 'remote_address', 'value': '127.0.0.1', 'text': 'Body', 'fields': [] } ] } ],};

obj.fields[1].fields[1].fields.push({'name' : 'remote_address',
 'value' : '127.0.0.1',
 'text' : 'Headers',
})
console.log(obj.fields[1].fields[1].fields)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Just wondering If it is possible to do it recursively?

Comment: Yes that is possible.  What would be the rules to decide where to insert?

Comment: Well, Like the format followed in the object, I need to create a property named "fields" which holds an array of items whenever a node has a child node and do that recursively to completely transform another json object to this format

Comment: So please ask a new question with actual input and expected output examples